# How to hide a parts of text after a special symbol, using html and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, hide

I'm trying to hide a part of every user email, registered in a website.

So lets say I have get `zero@example.com` and I want to hide everything after the "@". And only show it if someone clicks on whats left of the email.

Any help would be appreciated.

This just hides everything.

```
<p>
<button onclick=".hide('#email')">Hide</button>
<button onclick=".show('#email')">Show</button>
 </p>

<div id="email">
<h2>zero@example.com<h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function show(){
        document.getElementById('trail').style.display = 'inline';
    }
    function hide(){
        document.getElementById('trail').style.display = 'none';
    }
</script>
<p>
    <button onclick="hide()">Hide</button>
    <button onclick="show()">Show</button>
</p>

<div id="email">
    <h2>zero<span id="trail">@something.com</span></h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use split ( => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split ) if you know what character to expect. In this case:

```
var full; // let's say, it already has a value (f.e. zero@something.com)
var visiblePart = full.split("@")[0];
```

and eventually you can do something like this on click:

```
function show(){
        document.getElementById("emailH2").innerHTML = full;
}
function hide(){
        document.getElementById("emailH2").innerHTML = visiblePart;
}
```

and

```
<h2 id = "emailH2">zero@something.com<h2>
```